# Hiding command line arguments for C program in Linux

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments

How can I hide the command line argument for C program running in Linux so that they aren't visible to other users via "w", "ps auxwww" or similar commands?

Comment: I've been told that mysql hides the password when a user types it in the command line, so a `w` or `ps` won't show it. Maybe you could try to see how it achieves this (I mean, when called like `mysql -u foobar -ppassword`, `w` or similar commands show `mysql -u foobar -pxxxxxx`. Other than that I cannot help you (but I agree with @paxdiablo, if you don't want them to be visible, don't use that data as command line argument).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/592744/how-to-hide-a-password-passed-as-command-line-argument

Answer (score 8):

It's actually rather difficult (I'll stop short of saying impossible since there *may* be a way I'm not aware of) to do this, especially if a user has access to the `/proc` file system for your process.

Perhaps the best way to prevent people from seeing your command line arguments is to not *use* command line arguments :-)

You could stash your arguments in a suitably protected file called (for example) `myargs.txt` then run your program with:

```
myprog @myargs.txt
```

Of course, you'll have to modify `myprog` to handle the "arguments in a file" scenario.

Alternatively, you could set the arguments into environment variables and have your program use `getenv`.

However, I'm not aware of *any* method that can protect you from a suitable-empowered process (such as one run by `root`).

Comment: I don't think it's that difficult. If I remember right, most/all of the security enhancement patchsets for Linux add an option to change the permissions on `/proc/NNNNN` entries to `0700`, and there might even be a mount option for it in the default kernel nowadays. (The only reason I'm writing this as a comment rather than an answer is that I haven't checked on it.)

Comment: Even if you stash your args in a file, you still have a program running for a fraction of a second with the visible args before they are stashed. if a user runs the w command at just the right moment, they still aren't protected.

Comment: Can someone confirm that /proc/NNNNN is the only place that contains command line arguments? And is there any way to change permissions only for /proc/NNNNN only for some particular process (i.e. start process with these permissions changed?) Any link with further info would be appreciated.

Comment: A suitably empowered process can view _everyone's_ information, even down to the memory held in their address spaces. It's hard to hide information from such a beast :-)

Comment: @Chris, I didn't mean the _program_ put the args in a file, I meant the _user._ Then the only thing passed on the command line would be the string "@myargs.txt". You don't care who sees _that_ since all it reveals is a file name - the actual args never show up on the command line. But, again, a powerful-enough process can just go look inside your file.

Answer (score 8):

Modify the content of argv in your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay (long int msecs)
{
        clock_t delay = msecs * CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000;
        clock_t start = clock();
        while (clock() - start < delay);
}

void main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 2) 
    {
        printf ("%s\n", argv[1]);
        delay (6000);

        argv[1][0] = 'x';
        argv[1][1] = '.';
        argv[1][2] = 'x';

        printf ("%s\n", argv[1]);
        delay (5000);
        printf ("done\n");
    }
    else printf ("argc != 1: %d\n", argc);
}
```

Invocation:

```
./argumentClear foo  
foo
x.x
done
```

Result, viewn by ps:

```
asux:~ > ps auxwww | grep argu
stefan   13439 75.5  0.0   1620   352 pts/5    R+   17:15   0:01 ./argumentClear foo
stefan   13443  0.0  0.0   3332   796 pts/3    S+   17:15   0:00 grep argu
asux:~ > ps auxwww | grep argu
stefan   13439 69.6  0.0   1620   352 pts/5    R+   17:15   0:02 ./argumentClear x.x
stefan   13446  0.0  0.0   3332   796 pts/3    S+   17:15   0:00 grep argu
```

Remark: My delay-function doesn't work as expected. Instead of 11 seconds, the program runs in about 2-3. I'm not the big C-programmer. :) The delay-function needs improvement here.

Comment: As per Chris H, wouldn't 'ps auxwww' run at the right moment (before the program modifies the argv still reveal the command line arguments?

Comment: Well, of course. Before the program hides the parameters, they aren't hidden. Since I know of no program, which can travel in time, to hide them in the past. maybe you can prohibit the usage of ps and other programs, but I don't know how to find a list of all wellknown programs. And the user must be stopped from writing/installing own programs. Or the kernel has to be modified. You would need to kick the user, and stop his processes, start the program which modifies its arguments, before the user relogged in. If you try to hide passwords, perhaps the sudoers-file with NOPASSWD ...

Comment: ... and ssh with pre shared keys and trusted hosts is a better soluition.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that information is stored in kernel space.  Short of writing a kernel module, you will not be able to hide this information because any program can query the proc filesystem to see the command line arguments (this is what ps does).

As an alternative, you can read in your command line args on stdin then populate an array to pass to the command line argument handler.  Or, better yet, add support for your program to read a configuration file that contains the same command line argument information and set the permissions so that only the owner can read the file.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the arguments from the ps command, you could use the hack i always use:

`sprintf(argv[0], "My super long argument list`

");

**Be sure to use spaces of about 3 lines using the space bar, otherwise the compiler will trow an error !**
**Keep in mind to change argv[0] after parsing the command line !**

```
59982 pts/1    SLl+   0:00 My super long argument list

strings /proc/59982/cmdline
My super long argument list
```

It's a hack, but an intruder will issue a "ps axw" first.

**Always monitor mission critical server and check the logged in users !!!**